# Using Like operator in sql code. Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join, sql-like

i want to use 4 to 5 tables in the code. But between the code i need to use the like operator to use the contains property. I have written a code but the code is giving syntax error. Please advise.

```
SELECT 
    [RCDT Database].FUNCTIONALITY, 
    [RCDT Database].SPECIFICATION, 
    [RCDT Database].[TEST NAME]
FROM SelectedClearingName 
INNER JOIN Clearing ON (SelectedClearngName.ClearingName=Clearing.ClearingName) 
INNER JOIN FunctionalityWiseClearing ON (Clearing.ClearingName=FunctionalityWiseClearing.Clearing) 
INNER JOIN SelectedValues ON (FunctionalityWiseClearing.Functionality=SelectedValues.ListBoxValues) 
INNER JOIN [RCDT Database] ON ([RCDT Database].FUNCTIONALITY Like "" & [SelectedValued.ListBocValues] & "" 
INNER JOIN SelectedPaytype ON ([RCDT Database].[PAY TYPE]=SelectedPaytype.PaytypeValue;
```

Comment: Isn't the syntax error related to ampersands? In TSQL you probably should use 'AND' operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Access (tagged) SQL it would be:

```
Like "*" & [Selectedvalues.ListBoxValues] & "*"
```

Edit:

Reduce it to:

```
SELECT 
    [RCDT Database].FUNCTIONALITY, 
    [RCDT Database].SPECIFICATION, 
    [RCDT Database].[TEST NAME]
FROM 
    [RCDT Database],
    SelectedClearingName 
INNER JOIN 
    Clearing ON (SelectedClearngName.ClearingName=Clearing.ClearingName) 
INNER JOIN 
    SelectedValues ON (FunctionalityWiseClearing.Functionality = SelectedValues.ListBoxValues) 
INNER JOIN 
    FunctionalityWiseClearing ON (Clearing.ClearingName=FunctionalityWiseClearing.Clearing) 
INNER JOIN    
    SelectedPaytype ON ([RCDT Database].[PAY TYPE]=SelectedPaytype.PaytypeValue
WHERE
    [RCDT Database].FUNCTIONALITY Like "*" & [SelectedValued.ListBocValues] & "*"
```

What's missing here are the convoluted parenthesis of Access SQL that I never can recall.

So, remove the Where clause, use the GUI designer to create the inner joins, then add the Where clause.

Comment: it is still not working.  It shows syntax error and highlights rcdt database.specification

Answer (score 0):

seems you have to much () around join elements

```
SELECT 
    [RCDT Database].FUNCTIONALITY, 
    [RCDT Database].SPECIFICATION, 
    [RCDT Database].[TEST NAME]
FROM  SelectedClearingName 
    INNER JOIN Clearing ON (SelectedClearngName.ClearingName=Clearing.ClearingName)
    INNER JOIN FunctionalityWiseClearing ON (Clearing.ClearingName=FunctionalityWiseClearing.Clearing) 
    INNER JOIN SelectedValues ON (FunctionalityWiseClearing.Functionality=SelectedValues.ListBoxValues)
   ...........
```

Comment: It is still not working..Please have a look. FROM  SelectedClearingName 
    INNER JOIN Clearing ON (SelectedClearngName.ClearingName=Clearing.ClearingName)
    INNER JOIN FunctionalityWiseClearing ON (Clearing.ClearingName=FunctionalityWiseClearing.Clearing) 
    INNER JOIN SelectedValues ON (FunctionalityWiseClearing.Functionality=SelectedValues.ListBoxValues) 
    INNER JOIN [RCDT Database] ON ([RCDT Database.FUNCTIONALITY Like "*" & [SelectedValued.ListBocValues] & "*"
    INNER JOIN SelectedPaytype ON ([RCDT Database.[PAY TYPE]]=SelectedPaytype.PaytypeValue;

Comment: there was also wrong closing ] for RCDT Database .. asnwer  updated

Answer (score 0):

MS Access requires parentheses around `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT [RCDT Database].FUNCTIONALITY, [RCDT Database].SPECIFICATION, [RCDT Database].[TEST NAME]
FROM ((((SelectedClearingName INNER JOIN
         Clearing
         ON SelectedClearngName.ClearingName = Clearing.ClearingName
        ) INNER JOIN
        FunctionalityWiseClearing
        ON Clearing.ClearingName = FunctionalityWiseClearing.Clearing
       ) INNER JOIN
       SelectedValues
       ON FunctionalityWiseClearing.Functionality = SelectedValues.ListBoxValues
      ) INNER JOIN
      [RCDT Database]
      ON [RCDT Database].FUNCTIONALITY Like "" & [SelectedValued.ListBocValues] & "" 
     ) INNER JOIN
     SelectedPaytype
     ON ([RCDT Database].[PAY TYPE] = SelectedPaytype.PaytypeValue;
```